# UIAlertController not working with Rx-Single

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

So, I added this extension function to the `PrimitiveSequenceType` to show a loader on screen when making a network call

```
extension PrimitiveSequenceType where Trait == SingleTrait {
    
    func subscribeWithLoader(showLoaderOn viewController: MyUIViewController, onSuccess: ((Element) -> Void)? = nil, onFailure: ((Swift.Error) -> Void)? = nil)-> Disposable {
        let loader = viewController.showLoading()
        return subscribe { (element) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                loader.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    onSuccess?(element)
                })
            }
        } onFailure: { (error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                loader.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    onFailure?(error)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my showLoading function

```
func showLoading()-> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.medium
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return alert
    }
```

But the loader never stops. Can anybody let me know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very Rx like, but it works... except for one edge case. You dismiss the alert on success and on failure, but what if the Single is disposed without emitting either? Then the alert won't dismiss.

Try something like this instead:

```
extension PrimitiveSequenceType where Trait == SingleTrait {

    func withLoader(showLoaderOn viewController: UIViewController) -> Single<Element> {
        func loadingController() -> UIAlertController {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
            loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.medium
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
            alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
            return alert
        }

        return Single.create { fullfil in
            let loader = loadingController()
            viewController.present(loader, animated: true)
            let disposable = self.subscribe(fullfil)
            return Disposables.create {
                disposable.dispose()
                loader.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you like wrapping view controllers up like this. Check out this library... [Cause-Logic-Effect](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, but it is behaving the same `UIAlertController` is not going away.

Answer (score 0):

So, I end up adding a delay like this

```
extension PrimitiveSequenceType where Trait == SingleTrait {
    
    func subscribeWithLoader(showLoaderOn viewController: MyUIViewController, onSuccess: ((Element) -> Void)? = nil, onFailure: ((Swift.Error) -> Void)? = nil)-> Disposable {
        let loader = viewController.showLoading()
        return subscribe { (element) in
            onSuccess?(element)
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    loader.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        } onFailure: { (error) in
            onFailure?(error)
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    loader.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        } onDisposed: {
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    loader.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem was `onSuccess` (that means calling `loader.dismiss`) was getting called even before `UIAlertController` could show itself. So, by adding a delay of 500ms solves the issue the `UIAlertController` is going to have enough time to show itself, and then we are dismissing it.

Open to new ideas and improvements.